# Adding an empty row to a specific row index of a datatable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, webforms, row

I want to add an empty row in some place of my datatable. for example in row number five!
i searched and tried these codes but they didn't work. and the row was added at the first line of my gridview.

```
DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr2, 5);
```

and this:

```
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(),5);
```

i use asp.net webforms. Regards

Comment: When you inspect dt in the debugger after inserting the row, is the new row at position 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct. This code will add a new row to row index 5. But it is adding row to first line of your `gridview` that's because your `datatable` may be do not have any other rows. If your `datatable` do not have at least 0-6 index rows it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about the sorting! i add this to my code after the sorting and fixed!

```
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

thanks for suggests!